# Where can I change the URL for a Google+ business page?

Tags: google-plus

Where can I change the URL for a Google+ business page?

I've tried looking in the Google+ dashboard, but couldn't find anywhere to do it.

Answer (score 1):

## for Google+ non-business page:

- If there is a custom URL available for your account, you will see a banner below your name on your Plus profile.
- Click the link in the banner.
- You’ll see the custom URLs you can choose from. You may also need to add a few letters or numbers in the text box to make it unique to you.
- Next to **I agree with Terms of Service** click the checkbox.
- Click **Change URL**.
- When you’re ready to add your custom URL to your profile, click **Confirm**.

**Rules for getting a custom URL:**

There are a few rules to keep in mind when you’re trying to get a custom URL. If you’re having trouble, make sure:

- You have ten or more followers (people who have added you to their circles)
- Your account is at least 30 days old
- Your profile has a profile photo
- Your account is in good standing
- You do not try to get 4th custom URL in past 2 years with your name

**[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODZj1w6U1XQ)**

---

## for Google+ business page:

- Sign in to **[Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/?ppsrc=GPDA2)**
- Click **Business Pages** at the top of the page, then click **Manage this page** for the page you'd like to manage
- Click the three dash menu and choose **Google+ page**
- Click the **About** tab, and under **Get your custom URL**, click **Get URL**. You won't see this option if your page doesn't meet the eligibility requirements.
- You’ll see the custom URL you’ve been approved for, which you aren’t able to change. You may also need to add a few letters or numbers to make it unique to you.
- Check the box next to **I agree to the Terms of Service**. Click **Change URL** in the bottom left corner
- You may be asked to verify your account using your mobile phone number. To do this, you’ll need to:

  - Enter your mobile phone number when prompted, and click Send code in the bottom left corner
  - Check your phone for the code that was sent to you
  - Enter that code in the box on your screen, then click **Verify** in the bottom left corner
- Click **Confirm choice** to permanently add your URL to your profile